# Deleting multiple MySQL items using checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, sql-delete, delete-row

I have a form that enables user to select several items:

```
<table>
<form name="delete" action="proceed.php" method="post">
<?php 
 require_once 'cnn.php';
 $viewPhoto = mysqli_query($cnn, "SELECT * FROM competition WHERE round = 2 ORDER BY id Desc");


                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($viewPhoto)) {    ?>

<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"></td>
<td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
<td><img title="" src="<?php echo $row['url']; ?>"  width="178" height="150" /></td></tr>                   

<?php } ?>
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete items">
</form>
</table>
```

The proceed.php then includes:

```
<?php
 require_once 'cnn.php';
 $sql = mysqli_query($cnn, "SELECT * FROM competition");

 if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
   foreach ($_POST["check"] as $id){
   $sql = "DELETE FROM soutez WHERE id='$id'";
}
   echo "Items deleted";
}
?>
```

However, the items are not deleted from database. Where could be the mistake?

Comment: Are you getting any error? Also mention where you could stucked?

Comment: hint: there is no `mysqli_query()`. you did not execute it. tip: use parameterized queries :)

Comment: Maybe this is relevant: You are selecting from "competition" and deleting from "soutez".

Comment: @JeremyMiller : How do you say that? User doesn't share any `DB schema`. Is there any rules `where` we select, on that table record only can able to delete?

Comment: Jeremy: It was just a mistake in my translation: competition = soutez in Czech :)

Comment: OK.  I was just reading the code and read the statements.  No idea where Rangith's question comes from b/c you can clearly see in the question the different names.

Comment: @kevinabelita Should not be the row in proceed.phpb "$sql = mysqli_query($cnn, "SELECT * FROM competition");" enough?

Comment: @JanMares im not referring on the select. im referring on the delete. check out [`mysqli_bind_param()`](http://jp2.php.net//manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) for safer queries. its not safe directly inserting post values on your query.

Comment: Thanks @kevinabelita. Already found the solution in answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing executing actual query in loop for deleting record

```
<?php
 require_once 'cnn.php';
 $sql = mysqli_query($cnn, "SELECT * FROM soutez");

 if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
   foreach ($_POST["check"] as $id){
   $sql = "DELETE FROM soutez WHERE id='$id'";
   //Here you are missing below statement
   mysqli_query($cnn, $sql);
}
   echo "Items deleted";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Sadikhasan. This is perfect!